# Basic Spree 2.0.3 app deployment to Heroku not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, spree

I'm trying to get the most basic app up and running and I'm getting the famous "sorry something went wrong"

I'm following this guide: http://guides.spreecommerce.com/developer/heroku.html.

I generate a new vanilla app and successfully deploy it to Heroku.  I do the required changes to use postgres.  "heroku open" shows me the expected rails splash screen.  Then:

```
spree install --auto-accept
```

I follow the guide, add the ruby version, make the minor changes spree.rb and application.rb

Then

```
> git add .
> git commit -am "added spree"
> git push heroku master
> heroku run rake db: migrate
```

localhost:3000 shows me a happy spree app, missing the pictures because they are supposed to be on s3, but, heroku is broke.  My "heroku logs" has pages that look like this:

```
2013-08-06T23:30:04.173821+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/act
ionpack-3.2.13/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
2013-08-06T23:30:04.173985+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/act
ivesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrumen
t'
2013-08-06T23:30:04.174527+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/jou
rney-1.0.4/lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
2013-08-06T23:30:04.174857+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rac
k-1.4.5/lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
2013-08-06T23:30:04.175424+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/act
ionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
2013-08-06T23:30:04.175577+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rac
k-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:185:in `lookup'
```

Now, when I run the heroku migration, I get the deprecation warnings that I have "Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins!" but from what I've read that's not what is breaking it.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to seed your Spree application.

```
heroku run rake db:seed
```

This brings in,

1. Countries
2. Roles
3. States
4. Zones

https://github.com/spree/spree/tree/master/core/db/default/spree

This seed data is required to load the default home page.